# H2 Database Load Data from a Script

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to load some data from a script in a H2 database in a spring boot application but I am getting the File Not Found Exception. I have the yml file and Data File in the same directory. The two files exists in src/main/resources/config

```
 url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pdmp_app\;runscript from 'LoadData.sql'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using H2 script execution, I would suggest to use [Spring Boot initialization SQL scripts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). Just place your script into file `src/main/resources/data.sql` and Spring Boot will take care of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked for me

```
runscript from 'classpath:LoadData.sql'
```